# PHP code with errors

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails, permalinks

This is a code of a PHP WordPress page and the permalink do not work. What is wrong with this code?

```
echo '<p>';  
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : 
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" rel="bookmark">' . the_post_thumbnail( 'large-thumb' ). '</a>';  endif; echo '</p>';
```

Comment: Does it work if you do `get_the_permalink()` instead of `get_permalink()`?

Comment: Hi Andy, no neither with the get_the_permalink()

Comment: But you get the thumbnail fine?

Comment: I think it's `the_permalink()` if you dont pass an ID. otherwise it's `get_permalink($post->ID)`

Comment: Yes the thumbnail fine

Comment: I found the following backup solution:                echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . __('Read ', 'photo') . get_the_title() . '" rel="bookmark">';
                     the_post_thumbnail('index-thumb');

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you so much